# Typo3 DCE field configuration is empty

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

Dear Stackoverflow community,
i have a problem with the typo3 dce extension. I did not find anything from searching and have not seen this problem in any time.

When i create a field in the dce there should be a configuration in the textarea below the dropdown menu. (picture)
[Empty DCE configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwPlb.png)

I can not create a working dce without this configuration.
I think it is a general problem but i do not know which one and from where it comes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

even if I dont work with DCE i got two possible solutions for you:

1. Looks like the extension requires silently fluid or css styled content included, so you can try to add them to your template (at the template configuration -> includes). Try "fluid_styled_content" first.
2. The second possible solution is a missconfiguration. Cause I dont know the structure i can just refer to the extension documentation -> [User Manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dce/Tutorial/Index.html)